# How to calculate minimum temperature of a reaction?

Tags: energy, reactivity

For burning ethanol (its reaction with oxygen), we need a minimum activation energy (a minimum temperature) to start the reaction.

Is it possible to calculate what are the minimum temperatures required for burning ethanol and methanol to compare them?

Comment: You want [flash point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_point) or [autoignition temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoignition_temperature)?

Comment: If you mean this on a conceptual level: There are tables with bond energies; compare the intermediate form with the educts and calculate. If that is actually your question, I'll elaborate further.